# How to use include:local within a script used by include:project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab 16.1.2 Community Edition.

I have one repository (**ONE**) that uses the scripts stored in a second repository (**TWO**).

within ONE I include a main.yml from **TWO** repository via `include:project`. within this file `include:local` is used to include other files from the **TWO** repository.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> Unable to create pipeline Local file
> `/gitlab/PipelineScripts/child-pipelines/check.yml` does not exist!

How to solve it?

**`/.gitlab-ci.yml` in Repo ONE:**

```
include:
  - project: 'project-prefix/pipelinescript'
    ref: 'main'
    file: 
      - '/gitlab/PipelineScripts/pipeline.yml'
```

**`/gitlab/PipelineScripts/pipeline.yml` in Repo TWO:**

```
stages:
  - main

check-scripts:
  stage: main
  trigger:
    include:
    - local: '/gitlab/PipelineScripts/child-pipelines/check.yml'
    strategy: depend
```

**`/gitlab/PipelineScripts/child-pipelines/check.yml` in Repo TWO:**

```
stages:
  - test

check-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test job"
```

But it is working within repo **TWO** so I assume in principle the paths are correct.

**`/.gitlab-ci.yml` in Repo TWO:**

```
include:
  local: '/gitlab/PipelineScripts/pipeline.yml'
```

Comment: Rather than describing your code you should provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

your problem occurs due to many reasons

- Double-check the `Name` and  `path` and `tags` specified in the include:local directive within main.yml in your ONE repository. Ensure that the path is correct and matches the actual location of the general.yml file in the SEC repository.
- Check repository access permissions & privileges are correct.
- Instead of relying on include:project, you can try using full URLs for the file you want to include in the ONE repository.
  for example

  ```
  include:
    - remote: 'https://gitlab.com/SEC/repo/-/raw/master/general.yml'
  ```
- GitLab provides a CI Lint tool that allows you to validate your .gitlab-ci.yml file. You can access it by going to CI/CD > Pipelines > CI Lint in your GitLab project. Use this tool to check for any syntax errors or misconfigurations in your CI file.

Comment: I assume the scripts in repo two are correct as they are working properly within the repo **TWO** context. But when using as reference to repo **ONE** they are not working